# Ubuntu LTS vs regular release

Tags: ubuntu

I was wondering, what is the difference between the LTS (Long Term Support) and the regular versions of Ubuntu? I know, the LTS releases are supported 3 and 5 years (desktop and server), but what difference does it make e.g. if I use 8.10?

Is it possible, in a couple of years I won't get any security updates for 8.10, only for 8.04 LTS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's it exactly.

The non LTS versions will stop receiving bug fixes + security / feature updates after 18 months, whereas the LTS versions get updates for longer (3/5 years).

Comment: Ah 18 months, this was what I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible, in a couple of years I won't get any security updates for 8.10, only for 8.04 LTS?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

As the LTS releases will have to be maintained for a long time, presumably more care goes into checking the versions of the software that goes into them and there is a more rigurous QA on it.

But that is just my complete outsider's impression.